# display Json Ajax response and fill it in HTML

Tags: html, json, jquery

I working on feature like  **facebook notification** Or **stackoverflow** notification

[image: facebook notification]

when i press on the **world icon** an Ajax request sent , the response is JSON 
but the html and the words inside the notification will change depends on the action ( comment, like  etc )
the Question is

how to deal with the HTML ? in the php code ? 
or to use libraries like [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure/)
Is there any better library ?

is it the correct way to use JSON in response ?

Comment: This is too general a question. It sounds like you need to do some more research and play around with some code. If, after that, you have a specific, code-based question, we are here to help.

Comment: @Utkanos Actually I did a research but i didnt find the best way to do that, if you have some links please send me , thanks

Comment: @KJA The most efficient ( and my favourite ) way to do that is to use client-side templating library ( like Knockout.js or Underscore.js or whatever ) and parse JSON. JSON has to be created on the server side obviously. How to do that depends on the functionality you are trying to implement. It is not an easy task, believe me.

Comment: I will try to read more about underscorejs but what do you think guys about this Jquery plugin to deal with the html ? http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugin/jqote.